# download images and implement gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have several string arrays for downloading text data from mysql server on to android client app.I am able to display the title text (F_NAME) as listview.How do i download corresponding images for each text that are kept in a seperate folder on server(correct path to that folder is available,let it be my url).I need to display all images along with titles names from F_NAME[] as gridview.what changes should i make?pls edit my code and show me exact code,thanks in advance.
my java class and xml file:

```
public class MainMenu extends ListActivity {
InputStream is;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  String result = "";
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(my url);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
 }catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());}

try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
result=sb.toString();}
catch(Exception e){
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    int arrayLength=jArray.length();
    String F_NAME[]=new String[arrayLength];
    String F_ID[]=new String[arrayLength];
    String F_AVAIL[]=new String[arrayLength];
    String F_DESCP[]=new String[arrayLength];
    String F_COST[]=new String[arrayLength];
    for(int i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
           JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
           F_ID[i]=json_data.getInt("F_ID")+"";
           F_NAME[i]=json_data.getString("F_NAME");
           F_DESCP[i]=json_data.getString("F_DESCP");
           F_AVAIL[i]=json_data.getString("F_AVAIL");
           F_COST[i]=json_data.getInt("F_COST")+"";}
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu, F_NAME));
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
  int position, long id) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}});}
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} }}
```

Comment: Where is the xml file?

A bit unrelated, you should move downloading the images to a background process http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: xml file contains only a textview..i dnt knw how to create a suitable xml file for my image+text gridview.The main problem is java class,pls edit it for downloading and displaying images